# CMake: How do I get the project's directory from the toolchain file?

Tags: cmake

I have a project which is structured like this

```
project:
-- CMakeLists.txt
-- toolchain.cmake
-- source
-- includes
-- tools
   -- arm-toolchain
      -- arm-gnueabihf-gcc
      -- ...
-- libraries
   -- lib1
      -- ...
      -- CMakeLists.txt
   -- lib2
      -- ...
      -- CMakeLists.txt
```

I would like to set the compiler for another architecture inside the `toolchain.cmake` like this:

```
...
set (CMAKE_C_COMPILER "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/tools/arm-toolchain/arm-gnueabihf-gcc")
...
```

Unfortunately the variable `${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}` does change while compiling the project, at first it is:

```
CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR=/home/username/project
```

That's exactly what I expected. Unfortunately, it changes then to

```
CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR=/home/username/project/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp
```

Therefore I cannot use `${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}` as the root of my `project`-folder, is there another variable which does not change? Or, can I store the first value somehow? The problem is that the toolchain is invoked more than once, therefore a variable in which I store the initial value of `${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}` is overwritten on the second run.

Comment: It is very strange that `CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR` changes its value to building directory. Try `PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR` then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found an answer here: https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/16744

`CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR`  does indeed work in this case.

Comment: hum, sounds like it is an coincidence that it works therefore.... any other (bulletproof) ideas?

Comment: Sorry, I misspoke.  This is correct because when `cmake` processes the `toolchain.cmake` then `CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR` is the directory that holds the toolchain file.